# Join values in properties file

Tags: java, properties

For example, properties file has three properties:

```
val1 = 1
val2 = 2
val3 = 3
```

I would like to add fourth value which is in form of x.x.x (x is a number from previous val).

```
val4 = val1+.+val2+.+val3 = 1.2.3
```

I've done a lot of googling and haven't found a way to do that.

Comment: You mean you want to add `val4` in properties file?

Comment: Well i'd like to create val4 property, but i don't know how to value it with the parameters i need (val1+.+val2+.+val3). So if i change val1 = 2, then val4 = 2.2.3 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add variables in a properties file, however you can precompute it and write it down, or better yet, do this operation server side and register that specific value as a property. Something like :

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(MY_INPUT_STREAM);
        int val1 = properties.get("val1");
        int val2 = properties.get("val2");
        int val3 = properties.get("val3");
        properties.put("val4", val1 + val2 + val3);
```

Comment: I feel like i understood what you said and then i feel like i don't. What i understand is that you suggest that in my code i should get the properties values from val1,val2,val3 create a string for them and then with setProperty, set it as a val4?

Comment: You got your answer accepted. but please removing leading `+` from `properties.put("val4",  + val1 + val2 + val3)` *(Error)* to get `properties.put("val4",  val1 + val2 + val3)`